# How to set ComboBox/RepositoryItemComboBox datasource from a DataTable/TableAdapter?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, grid, devexpress

I am wondering how can I set `datasource` to a `ComboBox` in case I want to load data from database everytime my grid loads up.
This is what I did for now (I hardcoded 3 items just to see is it working)

```
 Dim riCombo As RepositoryItemComboBox = New RepositoryItemComboBox

 riCombo.Items.AddRange(New String() {"London", "Berlin", "Paris"})

 gridArticles.RepositoryItems.Add(riCombo)
 colArticles.ColumnEdit = riCombo
```

I am getting data from database throught DataTableAdapter, there I am writing methods which are triggering sql queries.

After DIMITRY suggestions:

```
 Dim riLookup As New RepositoryItemLookUpEdit()
        riLookup.DataSource = DataTableDobTableAdapter.FillDob(Me.DsOrders.DataTableDob)
        riLookup.ValueMember = "ID"
        riLookup.DisplayMember = "TITLE"
        riLookup.BestFitMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup
        GridView1.Columns("CODE").ColumnEdit = riLookup
        GridView1.BestFitColumns()
```

But what I am getting here for column where valuesin dropdowns should be is next:

[image]

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To fill the ComboBoxEdit editor's items, you can load data from your database to a list, then traverse all items in the list and add them to the **Items** collection. For example:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dataTable
        Dim cellData As String = DirectCast(row(columnName), String)  
        riCombo.Items.Add(cellData)
Next
```

Also, you can  use one of available [Lookup Editors](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument116008.aspx). These editors provide the DataSource property allowing you to load data from the data base to a list, and then assign this list to the **DataSource** property. Once this is done, simply set the **KeyMember** and **ValueMember** properties. This way, you don't need to fill items manually.

Comment: check for my Edit please, after your suggestion I made edit

Comment: What is the data type of GridView1.Columns("CODE")? Because the LookUpEdit is using an Int32 for the ValueMember, the GridColumn that uses the LookUpEdit should also be bound (GridColumn.FieldName) to an Int32.